# How to have WebApp find application properties on classpath in embedded jetty?

Tags: java, embedded-jetty, properties-file

We have an application which consists of a war file, and two properties files.
under normal circumstances we just drop the war into /webapps (jetty) and the config into /resources and everything runs up fine.

How do we do that with embedded jetty?
So I have a class file which can create an embedded jetty server and deploy the war file using :

*WebAppContext ctx = new WebAppContext(warfileLocation,"/");*

The server runs up, but the application doesn't start because it cannot find properties referenced by the application, which expects to find the .properties file on the classpath.

How to I deploy the config properties files programatically to the embedded jetty context?
Presumably by using some method on the context to reference files on my local disk?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting the .properties file under `projectRoot/src/main/resources`?

Comment: @NestorSokil you mean, embed the properties file into the meta-inf directory of the war? That's not going to work for me, because the properties files need to be kept outside of the war, since we have multiple environments, each of which uses the same war, but different properties

Answer (score 1):

A `WebAppContext` is classloader isolated from the Server classpath, making content available on the Server classpath unavailable to the `WebAppContext`.

You have two choices.

1. Flip the rules for the classloader isolation.

If you have only 1 WebAppContext in your embedded-jetty, and you don't care about the classloader isolation, call `WebAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true);`

2. Add the specific classpath entry you need to the `WebAppContext`.

You can call `WebAppContext.setExtraClasspath(String)` to add any arbitrary classpath entries you want to the `WebAppContext` prior to it being added to the `HandlerCollection` and started/deployed.

Comment: :) this is the answer.... I posted my discovery only seconds before you... Thank you for responding though.

Answer (score 0):

Your main goal is that your config ends up in the application's `classpath`. How you do it depends on your use cases.

You can put the .properties files under `project/src/main/resources` of your jar (the one that is running the embedded Jetty) which is automatically on the classpath.

This is useful in development, but this mean the configuration files will be included in your compiled jar file. That is unless you explicitly exclude them in your Maven/Gradle build file if you are using one. For production use you may want to externalize your configuration.

For example you can put the configuration files into an external `configs` folder and then run your jar using `java -classpath my.jar:configs/ Main`.

Any files in external `configs` folder should now be on your classpath.

There are of course other options to modify classpath. Please see [Setting the class path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html). If you still want to run using `-jar` option you can modify the classpath in `META-INF/MANIFEST.mf`. This option is described [here](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html).

Answer (score 0):

All,

I have found a solution using 'extraClassPath'

```
    //add application config properties
    String resourcesDirectory = System.getProperty("resourcesDirectory");
    if (resourcesDirectory!=null) {
        String ecp = ctx.getExtraClasspath();
        ecp = ecp + "," + resourcesDirectory;
        ctx.setExtraClasspath(ecp);
    }
```

Where ctx is the context returned from :

WebAppContext ctx = new WebAppContext(warfileLocation,"/");

Essntially you can add a local directory to the classpath of the embedded jetty server using this method. Anything in that path will appear in the classpath